# Pentaho: Unexpected error running shell (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid environment variable name:)

Tags: shell, pentaho

I'm attempting to run a .bat file in Kettle using the "Shell" function. However, Pentaho is throwing an error, showing that I have an invalid environment variable name. I'm at a complete loss as to what to do to resolve this, hence my post.

I've provided the output log file text below:

*2017/09/11 11:09:14 - Spoon - Starting job...

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_job - Start of job execution

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_job - Starting entry [test_batch.bat]

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_batch.bat - Running on platform : Windows 7

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_batch.bat - Executing command : cmd.exe /C "\Desktop\test_batch.bat"

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_batch.bat - ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : Unexpected error running shell [\Desktop\test_batch.bat] : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid environment variable name: "

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_batch.bat - ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid environment variable name: "

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_batch.bat -  at java.lang.ProcessEnvironment.validateName(Unknown Source)

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_batch.bat -  at java.lang.ProcessEnvironment.put(Unknown Source)

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_batch.bat -  at java.lang.ProcessEnvironment.put(Unknown Source)

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_batch.bat -  at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.shell.JobEntryShell.executeShell(JobEntryShell.java:568)

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_batch.bat -  at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.shell.JobEntryShell.execute(JobEntryShell.java:416)

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_batch.bat -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:716)

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_batch.bat -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:859)

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_batch.bat -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:532)

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_batch.bat -  at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:424)

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_job - Finished job entry [test_batch.bat] (result=[false])

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - test_job - Job execution finished

2017/09/11 11:09:14 - Spoon - Job has ended.*

If anyone can advise on the above it'd be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You are using the `Execute Shell Script`in a job. Did you used the `Insert script` or the `Script file name` ? And is the Working directory valid? If, yes, the next possible error is your script, which uses willingly or not, a environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run a bat file which executes a job? Not to run a command line 
from a job. Am I right?

In that case the command line is `kitchen /job=job-path`. Full doc is [here](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Kitchen+User+Documentation) and forum is (for example) [here](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?89374-Pentaho-Kitchen-running-job-from-command-line-Worked-for-me-Hello-World).

The command can be included in a bat file, provided the bat file can find the `kitchen` excutable. I have noticed that recently Pentaho removed the `kitchen.exe` to replace it with a `kitchen.bat`, from which you can copy the `call` line.

In case you want to run a transformation, the command is `pan.bat`.

Comment: It's actually the other way round - I'm planning to run the command line within the job itself. I've historically used this to execute R / Python scripts to generate data prior to the ETL itself.